# Insert php code inside sendgrid mail content html

Tags: php, concatenation, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid to send an email via PHP but I need to include a PHP script in the HTML content. I do not know how to perform the concatenation, it seems really delicate.
Here's my code:

```
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", '

/*
some HTML content
*/

/*PHP script starts here*/

'.myPHP Script {


      }//end of script
    .'

/*some more HTML content
        ');
```

The `'..'` concatenation does not work and the entire page fails to load. How do I go about this? I am not trying to output the code. I want it to actually execute.

Answer (score -1):

Don't make life difficult. What ever string you need to concat, put it in a variable and concat that. also note you can do string interpolation in PHP using the double quotes **"$variable"**.

```
$concatHTML = '';
$prodList = [...]; // assume we have products list here
for ($i = 0, $max = count($prodList); $i < $max; $i++) {
    $concatHTML += '<div>'. $prodList[$i] .'</div>';
}


$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/html", "
  //some html content here
  $concatHTML
");
```

EDIT

Concatenation could be done using the operator . (e.g.) `echo 'hi ' . $name`; where $name = 'some string' or using string string interpolation using double quotes and and placing (e.g.) `echo "hi $name"` you can add curly braces to make separate the variable from the other string like `echo "hi Mr.{$name}"`.

For the php code you want to include in the email is probably not valid.